# MS Access : Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a complex query(for me at least :) )  in MS Access that I need to write. I have the following Table [image]

What I want my query to show is: the column ID and Vers with the oldest date.For Example my  first entries in the query should look like this:

[image]

Basically I don't want the same ID-a and Vers to show more then one time in the query, and the criteria for excluding the "duplicates" should be the date.(only oldest to be shown)
Any Ideas on how to create this query? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
select a.* from tablename as a
right join (select vers,min(Date) as minimumdate,id-a from tablename
group by id-a, vers)b on a.vers=b.vers and a.date=b.minimumdate and a.id-a=b.id-a
```

Comment: Hi,thanks it works..but partially..in the sens that it only shows me the results for ID-a "24" ..I need this to do the same for all ID-a.

Comment: @adp Your result to according created query. I don't understand what you want update your question.....

Comment: see picture 2 from my question ,there are 4 entries , I used your query and I only get the first 3 entries,there should be more..see result from your query : http://i.imgur.com/bw7iULC.png

Comment: when i run the query it prompts me to "Enter Parameter Value for "a" and for "b.id"

Comment: Now check it. if still getting error then change column name of "id-a"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95335/discussion-between-adp-and-mukesh-kalgude).

Comment: It worked after I changed the Inner join to - right join. -Please update your answer ,and I will approve it after.